# How to allow backgrounding a process to survive a session termination?

Tags: php, linux, session, putty

So I'm using a Putty session to run a script on background.

my script can be located by

`cd /var/www/listingapp`.

Then I will run the command

`php /var/www/listingapp/public/index.php batch/GetPrefecture init > /dev/null &`

so I'm expecting that the script will run in background, but after I close the putty CLI and try to re-open it, the process can no longer be found when entering the command

`ps aux | grep /var/www/listingapp`

So this means it stopped. How do I make it to run in background when session is terminated?

Comment: Take a look at the `screen` utility (server side). It offers a wealth of options.

Comment: tried that but the client demands a one-time command for users.

Comment: @arkascha could I use something like, `screen php /var/www/listingapp/public/index.php batch/GetPrefecture init > /dev/null &` ?

Comment: Did you try to put your question to google? The first hit: [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8653/280048) - or [Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479/119732) - Btw, all this are rightly on different sites, as this is not a programming question.

Comment: You can setup the `screen` utility once _before_ the user connects and then just "use" it in subsequent sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nohup php /var/www/listingapp/public/index.php batch/GetPrefecture init &
```